# floating point comparison in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

I am used to compare the floating point with the following function.
However, I just check that c++11 provides some floating point comparison function like `isgreaterequal`.
My question is whether I should replace it with the functions in the standard?

```
bool isEqual(double lhs, double rhs, double epsilon = /std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
{
    if (lhs == rhs)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return fabs(lhs - rhs) <= ( (fabs(lhs) > fabs(rhs) ? fabs(rhs) : fabs(lhs)) * epsilon);
}
```

Comment: This is not a proper way to compare floating-point numbers anyway. First, it decreases false negatives at the expense of increasing false positives. Second, in the absence of specific knowledge of the preceding computations, there is no reason to expect the error to be proportional to the left-hand side. Third, a single epsilon of error is unusual for any but the simplest computations. Fourth, there is a huge discontinuity in the error tolerance; when `lhs` drops below `rhs`, the tolerance jumps from nearly `rhs*epsilon` to `rhs`, an increase of about 2**52.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 1. Such is finite-precision arithmetic. 2-3. Hence `epsilon` is a variable argument. 4. Check the parens; the smaller of `lhs` or `rhs` is multiplied by `epsilon`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You are correct about 4. 1: The fact that precision is finite does not make this correct. Other approaches should be used. 2: Passing a non-default value of epsilon does not change the fact that it is multiplied to be proportional to the values compared. 3: The default is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isgreaterequal/)

Using `isgreaterequal`, if either arguments are `NaN`, then the comparison is evaluates to false.

Using `>=`, if either arguments are `NaN`, then an `FE_INVALID` exception will be raised.

So, I think you should keep your function the way it is, as you probably would like to know if one of your arguments was `NaN`.

[**From C11 Draft N1570:**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)
p.516 Section F.9.3 Relational operators

> x < y → isless(x,y) (and similarly for ≤, >, ≥) Though numerically
>   equal, these expressions are not equivalent because of side effects
>   when x or y is a NaN and the state of the FENV_ACCESS pragma is
>   ‘‘on’’. This transformation, which would be desirable if extra code
>   were required to cause the ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception for
>   unordered cases, could be performed provided the state of the
>   FENV_ACCESS pragma is ‘‘off’’.

Comment: The spec for `isgreaterequal` et al says that `FE_INVALID` is raised by `>=`, but it's not the correct place for `>=` to be specified. In my experience, on Intel `FE_INVALID` never results from NaN, but I don't see where C even specifies that it may be raised. At best, reliance on an signaling comparisons is unportable.

Comment: [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Comparison-Functions.html#FP-Comparison-Functions) shows the same thing, but  I'm going to test this.

Comment: Ok I tested it, and no exception was raised.

Comment: I just go by the C11 spec, draft publication N1570.

Comment: Thanks, I found it at [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: An exception should be raise when `FENV_ACCESS` pragma is ‘‘on’’ according the the standard: Read p.516 section **F.9.3 Relational operators**.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! The magic incantation is `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`… I wonder how many platforms support it.

Comment: Note that in all implementations, floating-point exceptions are masked off by default and the result of a comparison involving NaNs is false; there is no difference in behavior between `>=` and `isgreaterequal`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - to manage floating-point exceptions (NOTE: "exception" here is **not** the same as "exception" in C++), use the functions in `<fenv.h>` or `<cfenv>`.